# How can we separate arabic names from a column in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to separate the arabic names from the column of a table in SQL Server 2012

[image]

I have input an image of the table in this it have arabic and English I need to separate the arabic names or I need to take only the arabic name of address from the table

Comment: What is the datatype of Address1 column?

Comment: Nvarchar is the datatype in that column only we can store arablic , in varchar we cannot store arabic languages

Comment: yes, nvarchar i used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter on Arabic strings via using `like N'%[أ-ي]%'`.

**Demo:-**

```
Create table #Emp
(id int ,
name nvarchar(100))

insert into #Emp values (1 , 'Ahmed Abdelqader')
insert into #Emp values (2 , N'أحمد عبد القادر')

select * from #Emp
where name like N'%[أ-ي]%'
```

**Result:-**

```
id  name
2   أحمد عبد القادر
```

**Update:-**

If you need to get the Arabic words ONLY, Use the next code:-

```
name like N'%[أ-ي]%' and name not like N'%[a-z]%'
```

Comment: how can we select the in between English character and numbers

Comment: @DonaSusanIssac `where name like N'%[a-z]%' and name like '%[0-9]%'`