# How to select all lines from a table that contain arabic or persian letters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working in SSMS and SQL.

I have a table that contains lines with Arabic letters. I'd like to filter those specific lines.

I figure there has to be a way to do it with regex somehow but I can't find any examples that show how to do it exactly.

Can anyone please assist?

This was my first attempt at this. I might have messed up the syntax. Please correct me if so.

```
A.Text like N'[ـا   اـب ـبـ بـ  بـت ـتـ تـ  تـث ـثـ ثـ  ثـج ـجـ جـ  جـح ـحـ حـ  حـخ ـخـ خـ  خـد دـذ ذـر رـز زـس ـسـ سـ  سـش ـشـ شـ  شـص ـصـ صـ  صـض ـضـ ضـ  ضـط ـطـ طـ  طـظ ـظـ ظـ  ظـع ـعـ عـ  عـغ ـغـ غـ  غـف ـفـ فـ  فـق ـقـ قـ  قـك ـكـ كـ  كـل ـلـ لـ  لـم ـمـ مـ  مـن ـنـ نـ  نـه ـهـ هـ  هـو وـي ـيـ يـ  يـأ أـإ إـؤ ؤـئ ـئـ ئـ  ئـآ آ ]'
```

This didn't work. It returned 2 results instead of thousands. I don't speak arabic and I don't know what it returned exactly so its not an option to compare.

Comment: you'd have to match for at least one of any of the possible characters in the arabic alphabet. So basically a giant character class I should think.

Comment: That would be unbelievably slow to do this. You would have to look at every single character of every single column of every single row. Another option would be to have a table of every possible character and do a sloppy wildcard join. No matter how you slice this it is going to be horrifically slow.

Comment: That was my first idea I wrote that first. However I don't speak arabic and have no idea how I did. I just copied all letters from a wikipedia page and tried. This i got 2 results where I know for a fact there should be thousands upon thousands. I guess I might have messed up the syntax. I'll add this line to the post.

Comment: Just a few Arabic letters here and there, or are those values expected to be using nothing but Arabic letters?

Comment: They are expected to be using nothing but arabic letters and spaces.

Comment: Then take a look at the first (non-space) character, if it's Arabic or not.

Comment: Same problem I need a way to figure out if the character is arabic or not.

Comment: Then you need a table with every arabic character in it. Are you doing this regularly? Because this is going to be horribly slow.

Comment: Are the Arabic letters consecutive Unicode characters?

Comment: No its a one of thing I need to do. It doesn't matter if its slow.

Comment: Try following solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885279/how-can-we-separate-arabic-names-from-a-column-in-sql-server-2012)

Comment: Apparently they are people in other posts say >> \u0621-\u064A << this should be all arabic letter, but I dont know how to use it SQL to get them.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode

Comment: THANKS @S.Jose this worked.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select *
from tbl
where arabic_field <> convert(varchar(8000), arabicfield) --this may be omitted
and arabic-field like '%['+nchar(0x0600)+'-'+nchar(0x06FF)+']%' --checks if contains at least an arabic char (unicode 0600–06FF)
```

Comment: I have various other alphabets in the DB including chinese, cyrillic, hindi and others. So I need a way to return specifically arabics/persian letters.

Comment: edited to include only arabic