# Retrieve data with specific language from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a column that contains a data of two languages **(Arabic and English)** and I want to retrieve them separately by identifying the type of its *uni-code or language*.

Am using **MS SSMS 2012**

Comment: update your question add that the related  tables schema a proper data sample  and the expected  result

Comment: You must have two separate columns for two languages. What is the issue in fetching data from one based on a condition. A case statement will do the trick.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885279/how-can-we-separate-arabic-names-from-a-column-in-sql-server-2012

Comment: To do what you ask you'd have to *scan all text*, every time. That's a bad idea. Add another column that identifies the language.

Comment: Unicode has character ranges that can be used to identify the language of specific *characters*. You'd need to check every single character in a string to determine whether all characters come from the US-ASCII or other ranges. T-SQL doesn't have such functions though. They are available in languages like C#, Python, R. You could create a SQLCLR function in C# but performance would be very bad. It would be a lot easier to store the language in a separate column, index it and use the desired language in a `WHERE` clause when loading the data

Answer (score 1):

Adding new column for language looks better way to handle it but you can use regular expression in where clause with "like" to differentiate Arabic and English (if you don't have other option).

```
--to get Arabic names for product
select * from Product where [name] not LIKE  '%[a-z0-9 .]%'

--to English names for product
select * from Product where [name] LIKE  '%[a-z0-9 .]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column is `NVARCHAR` since you have unicode characters, the way you can differentiate unicode from non-unicode is by comparing it's conversion with `VARCHAR`. Any character not available as `CHAR` will be `?`, and then the equality will fail.

```
SELECT
    T.TextColumn,
    IsUnicode = CASE 
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), T.TextColumn) <> CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), T.TextColumn) THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END
FROM
    YourTable AS T
```

You can change the length of the comparison at will (this example is for `100`), just make sure to grab a fair amount of characters so that at least 1 unicode value is fetched from the arabic texts.

I suggest you store the correct language tag of each text in another column so you don't have to do this check every time (it's a heavy process).

Please note that this solution ***won't fully differentiate*** english from arabic as the comments mentioned below.

Comment: This can only say if the string contains US-ASCII only or not. Or rather, if the text matches the server's collation or not, as `CONVERT(VARCHAR(100)` would use that to convert to `varchar`

Comment: Are there no English language characters that require nvarchar? For example what about café?

Comment: Both comments are correct, I'll leave the answer as a suggestion.

Comment: @DaleBurrell Careful about your assumptions. Does the "english" text contain emoji?